# Java - Extend a class that extend a Thread class

Tags: java, multithreading, extending

I'm studying for an exam about multi-threading, I started an exercise by myself in order to improve my ability with Java but I have a question:

Am I able to extend a class with another class made by me that extends `Thread` too?

I'm aware I can extend only 1 class in Java (and that I could implement `Runnable`, though I'm not very comfortable with that right now), but can I do it in cascade as said before? Or am I forced to use `implements`?
I'll throw my example to make you get exactly what would I do:

```
Character class -> extends Thread
Warrior class -> extends Character
Wizard class -> extends Character
```

and If I can do it, where could I use the `super()` function?

Comment: To summarize, you question seems to be: How does subclassing work? How do interfaces work, and how does threading work? This is too broad.

Comment: I'm not sure how you got to the multi-threading part of class without going through the inheritance part first.

Comment: You can extend a class, yes. You can also _try_ before asking.

Comment: Without seeing any actual code, I have to say that for classes with names such as "Character", "Warrior", and "Wizard" to be subclasses of `Thread` has pretty bad code smell.

Comment: Did you mean `Wizard class -> extends Warrior` ?

Comment: I know my lacks about Object Oriented Programming, but I'm trying to get mostly the part of cuncurrent tasks of this exam, because it is focused on it.
I obviously tried before to ask, and I asked because it didn't work, but I think it was not a problem with the super() call at this point :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentions, a class can only inherit (extend) from one other class
But hierarchical structure of extending classes does exist.

For example, you could have a

```
public class Animal{
}

public class Mammal extends Animal{
}

public class Monkey extends Mammal{
}
```

the `super()` is used within the constructor of each class

Comment: Ty for the help :)

Comment: Glad i could help you, please upvote and mark the answer as accepted for the future people looking for an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem doing that as long as your `Character` class is not declared `final`. Each subclass of `Character` inherits (indirectly) all the (non-`private`) behavior and structure of `Thread` (and also of `Object`) as well as the behavior and structure of `Character`. They can all be used as `Thread` objects.

The call `super()` invokes the default (no-argument) superclass constructor. It can only be used as the first line in a sub-class constructor. You can use the `super.blah()` syntax anywhere in your subclass code to invoke the superclass's `blah()` function.